# Spring Data/JPA - How can I check if a record already exists by name?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a question with Spring Data/JPA, I would like to know if there is any way to check if a name is already registered in the database with some function in the Repository with parameters.

I have the idea of ​​using a boolean, but I don't know how to execute it correctly to get the expected result.

```
@Query(nativeQuery= true, value="SELECT first_name FROM students WHERE first_name = :firstname")
boolean findByFirstname(String firstname);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean return type for an `EXISTS` style query is not supported by JPA.

However, you can work around this by creating a `default` method that has the signature you want and that calls the JPA method.

```
default boolean existsByFirstname(String firstname) {
    return !findByFirstname(firstname).isEmpty();
}
    
@Query(nativeQuery= true, value="SELECT first_name FROM students WHERE first_name = :firstname")
List<String> findByFirstname(String firstname);
```

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, as it's inaccurate. This functionality is available with Spring Data JPA as evidenced by Oliver Drotbohm's answer below and supporting documentation.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords), you can use the `exists` keyword and declare a derived query:

```
boolean existsByFirstname(String firstname);
```

This will project on the identifiers and check whether at least one result is returned.

Answer (score -1):

maybe it is not necessary for the native query.

```
    List<String> findByNameIgnoreCaseContaining(String firstName);
```

And in your service, you can check with an if statement if the response is empty or different to null.